# Use Docker in Linux VMWare VM with Volumes?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, docker-machine, vmware-workstation

Is it possible to connect to a Linux Docker engine running in a Linux VMWare virtual machine, running on Windows 10?  I need VMWare for other tasks... which means I need to disable Hyper-V (which Docker requires).  The configuration would be as follows:

- Windows 10 Enterprise ... running VMWare Workstation Pro v12
- Ubuntu 16.04.2 ... as a guest OS in VMWare
- Shared Folders running in VMWare sharing `C:\Source`
- Ubuntu VM mounting `C:\Source` (as `/media/source` probably)
- Docker Engine running within Ubuntu VM
- Docker container with Volume mounted at `/media/source`
- coding locally in `C:\Source` (using Sublime, Atom, whatever)
- changes being picked up by Docker container (via `nodemon`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Can this be done?  Yes.
Can this be done with VMWare?  I wouldn't **with VMWare**.

VMWare has issues dealing with Shared Folders on Windows 10.  The company behind VMWare switched HGFS drivers and there were problems as late as December 2016, which is when I finally gave up.

Now, if you are willing to do this with VirtualBox, then it works flawlessly:

```
flackey@devvms01: ~
$ ls
Backup  Source
```

[image: Shared Folders Example]

Here's what I currently do...

1. Disable Hyper-V in Windows 10;
2. Install VirtualBox & VirtualBox Extensions [(link)](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads);
3. Create the Ubuntu VM;
4. Before starting the VM, add the "Shared Folders" paths you need (see above);
5. Install Ubuntu;
6. Install `virtualbox-guest-dkms`;
7. Add your user to the `vboxsf` group: `sudo adduser $USER vboxsf`; and,
8. Create the mount point(s).

The commands would be:

```
    sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms  
    sudo reboot now

    sudo adduser $USER vboxsf  
    mkdir ~/Source  
    sudo mount -t vboxsf Source ~/Source  
    mkdir ~/Backup  
    sudo mount -t vboxsf Backup ~/Backup
```

- Note: You probably don't need to reboot.  I'm just anal like that.

After that, it works exactly as you described above.  You will be working in `C:\Source` directly in Windows 10.  The VM and Docker will function as if the files are local to the VM's file system.